# File Reader telling me that parameter 1 is not a blob?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filereader

I have a file input which returns what looks like a file path to me, and yet the fileReader is giving me the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
```

I feel like I am missing something here. Where am I going wrong?

```
import React from 'react';

    export default class TestPage extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                file: ''
            }
        }

        onChange(e) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
              this.setState({file: reader.result})
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.value);
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <input onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} type="file" name="file" />
                    <br />
                    <video width="400" controls>
                        <source src={this.state.file} type="video/mp4" />
                    </video>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does `reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])` work?

Comment: hey! that worked thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is pretty obvious, it's right there in the error. "Parameter 1 is not of type Blob" - in other words, readAsDataURL expects a Blob but that's not what you're passing it. [readAsDataURL is specifically meant to read Files or Blobs, not file paths.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) Meanwhile, [the `FileReader.result` parameter will end up being a String or ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result).

What you probably want to do is [pass in the input files array, not "e.target.value"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications), to readAsDataURL.

```
onChange(e) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
      this.setState({file: reader.result})
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: @SamarthSaxena You're going to have to provide more detail as to what you mean. Perhaps open your own question?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I discovered I was using the `onClick` event instead of the `onChange` event to trigger the file `read` function.